# CouchDB: Filter Functions in Views

Tags: database, search, view, filter, couchdb

I'm wondering if it's possible to use [Filter Functions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#filter-functions) when requesting a view something like: 
http://localhost:5984/db/myView/myMap?filter=myFilter.

I'm going to use [Complex Keys](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/views/collation.html) with separate views eventually but I'm wondering if this is possible. So far I tried but it's not showing me any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/ddoc/views.html) it's not possible to do so. You can pass keys to query your view but you can't filter it. Filter can be applied to _changes aswell as in replications.